# Get group chat membership from `chat.db`

Tags: messages, contacts, ichat, group, chat

I'm able to able to natively access my iMessages through `chat.db.` and associated contacts through the databases in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources` - is there any similar database for storing group chat membership/metadata?

AFAIK this information is not stored in `AddressBook` or `chat.db,` although it is possible to access the group chat name through the `chat` table in `chat.db`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a full answer, but I did find a good workaround!

The `handle` table which is joined by `chat_handle_join` allows you to get the users associated with a message sent in a group chat. By counting the distinct members in a group-chat, you're able to get something close to membership.

If anyone is curious, the final query to get all members of groupchat  (run on chat.db) might look a little like this

```
select 
    c.chat_identifier, 
    h.id 
from chat c
    join chat_message_join cmj on cmj.chat_id = c.rowid
    join message m on m.rowid = cmj.message_id
    join chat_handle_join chj on chj.chat_id = c.rowid
    join handle h on h.rowid = chj.handle_id
where 
    chat_identifier like '%chat%'
and 
    display_name is not null
group by 
    c.chat_identifier, h.id
```